# multithreading - using a thread to execute a function storing contents of a file in char **array?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers, file-io

Let's say I have a file named `file1.txt` with contents:

```
one
two
three
```

Here is my code with a segfault that occurs inside

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct example{
    char **file;
    char **array;
};

void *func(void *arg){
    struct example *ex = arg;
    char name[1025];
    FILE *fp = fopen(ex->file[0], "r");
    int k = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%1025s", name) > 0){
        ex->array[k] = name; // segfault happens here?
        k++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    char *sarray[5] = { NULL };
    struct example t;
    t.file[0] = "file1.txt"
    t.array = sarray;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, &t);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}
```

If I do a check:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("t array: %s and sarray: %s\n", t.array[i], sarray[i]);
}
```

I want the following output:

```
t array: one and sarray: one
t array: two and sarray: two
t array: three and sarray: three
```

Essentially, I want the contents of file to be stored into t.array from the function func and as a result, sarray will have the same values as well. Can anyone help me? I've tried and tested the while loop in func in main and it works, but I want it to work in func.

Comment: 'char **array;' has no storage allocated for it.  Also, when you fix that, your function should copy in the char array data from the local 'char name[1025];' , not just assign a pointer:(

Comment: ..or better, malloc the space in the function, read in the data and then you can safely just assign the pointer.  Saves a copy operation, though you may over-allocate some space.

Comment: @MartinJames Are you saying in func do ex->array = malloc(1025)? I don't understand what you mean with the rest though. Can you explain more with some code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to change few things.
Let's focus first on the main function and the structure example.
You are using struct example t where the fields **file and **array are not allocated.
Luckily, the statement t.file[0]="file1.txt" is okay.
However, if you want to manage n files, the statement t.file[i], with 0 <= i < n, you will get a segfault when 0 < i.
Why ? Because your t.file is not allocated. Therefore the statement t.file[0] is in reality *(t.file + 0) = *(t.file) that can point to the const char[] "file1.txt".
Next, you are doing t.array = sarray;
Keep in mind that using the symbol '=' is not equivalent to an allocation or a copy.

Now, let's have a look on the func function.
Why are you using 'void *' parameter ? Actually you know the type of arg variable.
Same remark as in the main function, you are using the symbol '=' in the statement ex->array[k] = name;
Here, it means that the  k-th element points to name.
There is no copy. As a consequence, all elements of ex->array will have the same value as name. Assuming no segfault, you should get 'three three three' and not 'one two three'.
Last but not least, if you have more than 5 lines in your file, you also get a segfault.

Therefore, you should allocate your memory and replace the symbol '=' by strncpy to copy the content of a buffer into antoher memory space.